# Apple Watch Kit load data on start up

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

How to quickly load data on Apple Watch? UserDefaults doesn't work since watchOS 2, so we can only use `WCSessionDelegate`, right?

Now, on Watch App start I call `wcSession?.sendMessage(someThing, replyHandler: someFunc, errorHandler: otherFunc)`, then on iPhone app I send back some data in

```
 func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any], replyHandler: @escaping ([String : Any]) -> Void)
```

And finally receive it on watch app in `func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any])`, but that takes like 3 seconds.

What would be better way to get data on start up?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the reply Handler function instead of initiating a new message. It should work faster.

Call this from watch:

```
func sendRequest() {
    if session.activationState == .activated && session.isReachable {
        session.sendMessage(["Watch Message" : "Request"], replyHandler: { (reply) in

            // Handle reply here

        }, errorHandler: { (error) in

            print("***** Error Did Occur: \(error) *****")
        })
    }
}
```

Handle and Respond on Phone:

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any], replyHandler: @escaping ([String : Any]) -> Void) {

    if let messageFromWatch = message["Watch Message"] {
        let messageData = messageFromWatch as! String

        // Message From Watch to Activate Watch Connectivity Session
        if messageData == "Request" {
            replyHandler(["Response" : data])
        }
    }
}
```